# SWT composite resize

Tags: java, swt

I am making an application in which I have a Composite, which has inside another composite with a few buttons. The thing is, when I resize the composite with the buttons, sometimes, the buttons are being hided. I solved this by replacing composite.layout() with composite.requestLayout() method. What is the difference between those 2 methods and why it's working fine with the requestLayout() and just sometimes with layout(), from what I've seen they are pretty much similar.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Composite.layout` requests that the composite and its children should be layed out again. If the composite's contents get bigger it does **not** tell the parent of the composite that it needs more space so some things may end up hidden.

`Composite.requestLayout` (actually `Control.requestLayout`) requests that all the ancestor controls of the control in the `Shell` should be layed out again (this is done asynchronously). This will adjust everything necessary to make space.

Comment: Thank you greg, very helpful!